# Django admin : How to show a model as inline inside another model, which is indirectly related

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline

I have models named user, authtoken and userdevice.

> ```
> class User(LifecycleModelMixin, AbstractUser):
>     email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
>
>
>
>  class AuthToken(models.Model):
>         objects = AuthTokenManager()
>         digest = models.CharField(
>             max_length=CONSTANTS.DIGEST_LENGTH, primary_key=True)
>         token_key = models.CharField(
>             max_length=CONSTANTS.TOKEN_KEY_LENGTH, db_index=True)
>         user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False,
>                                  related_name='auth_token_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>         created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
>         expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
>
> class UserDevice(models.Model):
>     token = models.OneToOneField(AuthToken, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auth_token")
>     device_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DevicesChoices.choices)
>     access_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=AccessChoices.choices)
>     device_brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
> ```

I need to show the userdevice inside the user detail page in admin panel as inline.

> Django Error admin.E202 'userdevice' has no ForeignKey to
> 'accounts.user'

Getting this error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/OskarPersson/django-nested-inline) library

Answer (score 0):

You need to link User model to UserDevice model.

models.py

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   token = models.OneToOneField(AuthToken, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auth_token")
   device_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DevicesChoices.choices)
   access_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=AccessChoices.choices)
   device_brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

class UserDeviceInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = UserDevice
   extra = 0

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ['email', 'slug']
   inlines = [UserDeviceInline]
```

Now in User Details you have Device info. [More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)